# Como fazer um webservice ser chamado automaticamente com php?

Tags: php

Olá, sou iniciante em php e possuo um sistema o qual salvo alguns dados no banco, como mensagens e imagens. Esse sistema possui um webservice também em php que pega todos esses dados e os envia zipados(texto em .pdf e a imagem em .jpg) para um usuário.

Gostaria de saber de que forma posso chamar esse meu webservice automaticamente a cada um período x de tempo.

No meu caso, o sistema deve enviar a cada 15 dias todos os arquivos que ainda não foram enviados para esse usuário. Ou seja, só preciso descobrir um meio automático de chamar esse webservice que criei.

Existe alguma função em php que faça esse tipo de chamada?

Comment: Crie um *script* que faz o que precisa e execute-o através das CRONs (ou tarefa agendada)

Comment: Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss, era isso mesmo que eu buscava.